# tagging a friend in a facebook post c# sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, tagging

I am trying to test the ability to tag friends in messages from our app. It posts to facebook just fine, caption, description, name, picture, and link all display as they should, but in message all it shows is the string in p_message.

```
string token = Request.Cookies["fbToken"]["value"];
var fbclient = new FacebookClient(token);
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
args["message"] = p_message + " @[1550577341:nick.rich.1232]";
args["caption"] = "This is caption!";
args["description"] = "This is description!";
args["name"] = "This is name!";
args["picture"] = "http://nowprovemewrong.com/Images/icon-2.png";
args["link"] = str_redirect_uri;
fbclient.Post("me/feed", args);
```

formatting @[id:username] any differently results in it appearing in the message, so i'm assuming facebook is recognizing it as something just not a tag

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to tag messages like this. The feature `@[1550577341:nick.rich.1232]` exists but it's for use in Open Graph tagging.

see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/#mentions